# ImageMagick error: 'mogrify: unable to open image issue'

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I'm trying to use ImageMagick for compressing images on my web-site. I've found a nice algorithm, implemented it, but getting error: ***"mogrify: unable to open image `thumb_preview_uVACfM5fhbE87num1fYGlQsmall.jpeg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695."***
Seems that I'm missing something, but can't figure out what exactly. Here's the command (i split it on several lines):

```
 mogrify 'uploads/images/preview_uVACfM5fhbE87num1fYGlQsmall.jpeg'
 -path uploads/images -filter Triangle -define filter:support=2 
-thumbnail 100 -unsharp 0.25x0.25+8+0.065 -dither None -posterize 136 
-quality 82 -define jpeg:fancy-upsampling=off 
-define png:compression-filter=5 -define png:compression-level=9 
-define png:compression-strategy=1 -define png:exclude-chunk=all
 -interlace none -colorspace sRGB 
-strip thumb_preview_uVACfM5fhbE87num1fYGlQsmall.jpeg
```

Comment: Do you have a file with that name?

Comment: @MarkSetchell no, I want the output file to have that name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `mogrify`, it uses the same output filename as input filename - i.e. it overwrites the input file. As such, your command is looking for `thumb_preview...jpeg` as an **input** file whereas you want it to use that as the **output** file.

You need to replace `mogrify` with `convert` and then the last filename will be interpreted as an output filename.

```
convert inputfile.jpg ... operations ... outputfile.jpeg
```

Comment: Yes, this helped! Thank you!